# How to achieve simplification in composition?

Tags: technique, composition, artistic

Simplification is a great tool for creating photographs with artistic quality – it stays away from unnecessary/obvious things and helps the image not to be “busy”.

I was searching various blogs and forums about how to simplify photographs. Most of the blogs and articles say the following two things:

1. Zoom in/ Crop
2. Use Shallow depth of field

A third tip seen some places is to use low shutter speed, if it is photograph of a lake, sea, etc. But I am not photographing water.

The above two pieces of advice do not add any artistic value, when I see the images. They just include fewer things – but they don’t look simple, albeit the fact that they have fewer elements.

Apart from these trivial bits of advice, what are the composition techniques/guidelines that will help to create `simplified` photographs?

Note: As you know the word "simple" and "simplified" are pretty much different, when it comes to design and composition.

Comment: Related: [What does it mean when something is "distracting"?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/62234/what-does-it-mean-when-something-is-distracting)

Comment: Reference: [Guidelines for Better Photographic Composition: Simplicity](http://photoinf.com/General/KODAK/guidelines_for_better_photographic_composition_simplicity.html)

Answer (score 5):

Simplification is achieved by removal of elements that would make up a more complex photo so that viewer could pay more attention to the remaining elements. Most often simplification is desired for [background](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2/4390/how-can-i-maximize-the-blurry-background-sharp-subject-bokeh-effect), but same methods can also be applied to subject.

There are several options of *what* elements to remove -

- **details** - perhaps the most common route; achieved by deliberate blurring, e.g. panning with a moving object, shallow focus, degraded optics;
- **physical objects** - relocation of props or background objects so the undesired items would not participate in composition;
- **colors** - using black-and white (or some other restricted color scheme) instead of full color;
- **field of view** - getting closer, using a longer focal length, cropping, shooting from behind an obstruction or a less revealing angle;
- **light** - leaving parts of composition unlit (or less commonly, oversaturated) will turn those areas into plain single color;
- **individuality** of objects - grouping/lining multiple items up, perhaps even pairing up their amount to work against [Rule of Odds](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/11475/4390/what-is-the-rule-of-odds).

Comment: +1 for the physical objects - you can't make a 'minimalist/simple' image out of just any old scene that you happen upon, you really need something that is free of distracting elements before you even begin.  Often it takes a lot of planning.

Comment: +1 as well for pointing out it can be applied to the subject. If the subject is a person, something as simple as having them dress with clothes of a single colour can help